# Largest value stored in 20 bits

Tags: assembly

I am assembly language student and yesterday my teacher asked me , what largest value can be stored in 20 bits for Signed Representation ?

I was confused. Kindly help me out

Comment: Should be easy enough for you to extrapolate from the tables at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Comment: What\`s the largest value that can be stored in 2 bits signed rep? 3 bits? 4? The principle is quite elementary.

Comment: Depends on interpretation of those bits, if you would split them into exponent:mantissa floating point encoding, let's say with bits allocated as 1:5:14, you can encode into 20 bits even value 1.0e30 ... (yeah, I know the teacher did ask about integer values, and the answers below are correct, but keep in mind the bits themselves can be interpreted any way you want, or better to say, any way the code wants).

Answer (score 4):

With signed numbers the highest bit is treated as the sign bit. (0=positive 1=negative)
That leaves 19 bits for the actual number when you only have 20 bits of storage.

```
0000_0000_0000_0000_0000b    Smallest positive number:      0

0111_1111_1111_1111_1111b    Largest positive number:  524287


1111_1111_1111_1111_1111b    Smallest negative number:     -1

1000_0000_0000_0000_0000b    Largest negative number: -524288
```